# Проблема с координатами элемента при скроле

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте!
Возникла проблема.
Есть `div` с `overflow-y=scroll`, в этом div'е есть поле ввода, нажимая на которое появляется календарик для выбора даты. Календарик появляется под элементом, всё чудесно, пока содержимое div'а влазит в него. Но вот когда появляется прокрутка, и наш элемент (под которым должен появиться календарик) находится в низу div'а, и чтоб до него добраться, нужно прокрутить слой, то нажав по элементу календарик появляется далеко внизу страницы.
Как я понял, скрипт календаря получает абсолютные координаты элемента от начала страницы и по этим координатам рисует себя, но нам ведь нужны относительные координаты от начала окна, так как элемент находится в прокрутке.
Координаты скрипт получает такими действиями:

```
 while (parent.offsetParent) {
    parent = parent.offsetParent;
    x += parent.offsetLeft;
    y += parent.offsetTop ;
  }
position задает себе absolute
слой календаря создается динамически скриптом
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно можно в верстке что-то изменить или как-то по-другому отсчитать координаты, к примеру, отнять от них координаты прокрученного div'а? Или другими методами.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, вы выводите календарик в div'е с position:relative. Координаты считаются относительно страницы, а выводится все относительно div'а. Выводите календарик в body.

Comment: календарь создает div, и присоединяет его к body
проблема в том что координаты считаются относительно страницы, и также выводятся,а элемент находится в прокрутке, и нужно координаты считать от окна наверное..

Comment: Хм. Если инпут находится внутри дива с прокруткой, тогда надо еще учитывать прокрутку этого дива...  
Есть еще вариант: обернуть инпут еще дивом и выводить календарь внутри этого дива.

Comment: position: fixed; ?

Comment: второй вариант конечно интересный, но этот календарик вызывается из разных инпутов и должен появляться под каждым. а вот как учитывать прокрутку дива??

Comment: Shurik, это вы про какой элемент спрашивали?если про календарь то он абсолют